# How do I reset the splits in Vim?

Tags: vim, nerdtree, minibufexplorer

I'm using [MiniBufExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=159) and [NERD tree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) to develop in Vim. I usually have the following screens:

```
MMMMMMMMMMMM
NNSSSSSSSSSS
NNSSSSSSSSSS
NNSSSSSSSSSS
NNSSSSSSSSSS
NNSSSSSSSSSS
```

where `N` is NERD tree, `M` is MiniBufExplorer and `S` is the file I'm looking at.

I sometimes forget to use `:sh` to get to a shell, and I hit `:q` on the `S` split, which makes it so toggling NERD tree will either make a full-screen NERD tree split or a full screen source view, but never where it was before where NERD tree was off to the left (MiniBufExplorer doesn't change).

How can I "reset" the splits to get the old behavior back after that? I've basically been doing `:qa` to completely exit Vim, but obviously that closes everything.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using sessions - make a session of your setup with

```
mksession
```

and restore it with

```
source Session.vim
```

if your splits get mucked up.

Think you'll need to use the session.vim plugin though if NERDTree is involved: see [Vim, NERDtree not recovered in session restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226905/vim-nerdtree-not-recovered-in-session-restore).

Answer (score 0):

not a direct answer to your question, but maybe something that will solve your problem:

https://github.com/jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs

> "When you close a file, the tab closes with it. No NERDTree hanging
>   open."

Nerdtree is just the worst thing to deal with. That plugin-for-a-plugin makes it bearable.